# Liferay use Freemarker instead of JSP inside a Portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-7

I am currently trying to use Freemarker instead of JSP for my Portlet but im not sure how. I tried to set up my project but im not sure what im missing, if my setup is even remotely correct. How do I support freemarker in my vue project?

When deploying the module, I get the following errors:

```
 Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.util.bridges.freemarker; version="[7.0.0,8.0.0)"_ [Sanitized]
```

Using MVCPortlet instead of FreeMarkerPortlet fixes the above issue but then I get:

```
Path /view.ftl is not accessible by portlet vue
```

Now I tried `/template/view.ftl` but that doesnt work either. To be honest im currently a bit lost and would appreciate some insight on how this works.

**This is where my .ftl files are:**

```
resource
  -- content
  -- META-INF.resources
  -- templates
     -- init.ftl
     -- vue.ftl
```

**Init.ftl**

```
<#assign aui = PortletJspTagLibs["/META-INF/liferay-aui.tld"] />
<#assign liferay_portlet = PortletJspTagLibs["/META-INF/liferay-portlet-ext.tld"] />
<#assign liferay_security = PortletJspTagLibs["/META-INF/liferay-security.tld"] />
<#assign liferay_theme = PortletJspTagLibs["/META-INF/liferay-theme.tld"] />
<#assign liferay_ui = PortletJspTagLibs["/META-INF/liferay-ui.tld"] />
<#assign liferay_util = PortletJspTagLibs["/META-INF/liferay-util.tld"] />
<#assign portlet = PortletJspTagLibs["/META-INF/liferay-portlet.tld"] />

<@liferay_theme["defineObjects"] />

<@portlet["defineObjects"] />
```

**view.ftl**

```
<#include "init.ftl">

<@liferay_ui["message"] key="free.caption" />

<script src="${renderRequest.getAttribute("main")}"></script>
```

**My java portlet class**

```
package vue.portlet;

import com.liferay.util.bridges.freemarker.FreeMarkerPortlet;
import vue.constants.VuePortletKeys;

import com.liferay.frontend.js.loader.modules.extender.npm.NPMResolver;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.portlet.Portlet;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;


@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
        "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.ftl",
        "javax.portlet.name=" + VuePortletKeys.Vue,
        "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
        "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user"
    },
    service = Portlet.class
)

public class VuePortlet extends FreeMarkerPortlet {
    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

        renderRequest.setAttribute("main", _npmResolver.resolveModuleName("vue") + " as main");

        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }

    @Reference
    private NPMResolver _npmResolver;
}
```

**My build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.js.loader.modules.extender.api"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib.util.freemarker.contributor"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.bridges"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.taglib"
    compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api"
    compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "osgi.cmpn"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations"

    cssBuilder group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.css.builder", version: "3.0.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, when building the plugin, the version of "com.liferay.portal.kernel" dependency must be raised to the actual version of the Liferay bundle in which you want to work on